# GUI on Raspbian OS

Tags: raspbian, gui

I am in my last year project dealing with raspberry pi that has the ability to record voice with my single tap on its touchscreen. I already knew how recording and playback works, what i really want an answer is the part where i could build an GUI for my "START" and "STOP" "PLAYBACK" button that executes the same command when typed on lxt terminal. Thanks yall

Comment: Hi. I'm a rookie Linux user. From what I understand, Rasbian has X graphical interface and I believe you use Xlib to write UI programs.

Maybe the Xlib tutorial on buttons would be a place to start?

http://xopendisplay.hilltopia.ca/2009/Mar/Xlib-tutorial-part-9----Buttons.html

On a button callback, you want to execute a command line? I believe the "system" function can do that for you.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm).  It's standard in python so you shouldn't need to install any modules.

I have written many GUI applications using tkinter and it works great for me, however I have never done so on a raspberry pi.  It shouldn't be any different though.

There are also [plenty of other libraries](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) if tkinter isn't for you.